# XmlDocument Prefix Not Being Outputted

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I am trying to add a prefix onto a few xmlnodes within a new XMLDocument (Created 100% from scratch, not loaded from a file etc).

In the simplest terms I have this :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement RootElement = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("root"));
foreach (string line in CSV)
{
    XmlElement navPointElement = (XmlElement) RootElement.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("navPoint"));
    XmlElement navPointTypeElement =(XmlElement) navPointElement.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("type"));
    navPointTypeElement.Prefix = "acp";
    navPointTypeElement.InnerText = nodeCount == 0 ? "cover" : "article";
}
```

There is much more code but this gives you an idea of what I'm doing. Now the document outputs fine, but it completely skips over the prefix declarations. I have read around about defining namespaces, and I tried to the following to no avail.

```
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("acp", "http://www.namespace.com");
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't quite find any documentation on it. The MSDN documentation for xmldocument prefix simply just adds the prefix much the same as I have done without the need for namespaces (Or atleast that's how they show it in their code samples).

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you do need a namespace. Something like `<acp:type/>` is invalid by itself because `acp` doesn't map to any namespace, which is what a prefix should do.

What you need to do is to set the namespace on the element you want to add on the call of CreateElement for the `type` element.

```
public class StackOverflow_10807173
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement RootElement = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(
            doc.CreateElement("root"));
        string[] CSV = "hello world how are you".Split(' ');
        int nodeCount = 0;
        XmlAttribute xmlnsAttr = doc.CreateAttribute(
            "xmlns", "acp", "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/");
        string acpNamespace = "http://www.namespace.com";
        xmlnsAttr.Value = acpNamespace;
        RootElement.Attributes.Append(xmlnsAttr);
        foreach (string line in CSV)
        {
            XmlElement navPointElement = (XmlElement)RootElement.AppendChild(
                doc.CreateElement("navPoint"));
            XmlElement navPointTypeElement = (XmlElement)navPointElement.AppendChild(
                doc.CreateElement("type", acpNamespace)); // namespace here
            navPointTypeElement.Prefix = "acp";
            navPointTypeElement.InnerText = nodeCount == 0 ? "cover" : "article";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
    }
}
```

One note: you don't really need to add the namespace in the root element; it's just that if you don't do that, you'll have the `xmlns:acp="yournamespace"` attribute in all of the `type` elements (since that prefix isn't in scope). Adding that in a parent element makes adding it in the children elements unecessary.

Comment: Works. Marked yours as the answer :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and I found the built-in .NET System.XML objects to be unable to do what I needed.

I needed to use the NAXML markup to create fuel price change records in our POS system.  ***SOME*** of the elements needed a "nax" prefix, while others didn't.  The System.Xml objects seemed to want to add it to ***all*** elements or ***none***.  I couldn't get it to just apply them to the elements I needed.

Because the System.XML objects didn't give me the granular control I needed, I ended up having to write out the Xml manually using a System.Text.StringBuilder.

Sample code from my app to give you an idea of how to do it:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n");
sb.Append("<FuelPriceMaintenanceRequest xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns=\"http://www.POSVENDOR.com/NAXML-Extension\" xmlns:nax=\"http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.POSVENDOR.com/NAXML-Extension FuelPriceMaintenance.xsd\">\r\n");
sb.Append("  <nax:TransmissionHeader>\r\n");
sb.Append("    <nax:StoreLocationID>" + StoreNumber.ToString() + "</nax:StoreLocationID>\r\n");
sb.Append("  </nax:TransmissionHeader>\r\n");
...snip...
sb.Append("</FuelPriceMaintenanceRequest>");
```

Comment: Oh boy! Here's hoping this isn't the final solution! At this point the app I am writing just converts a CSV into a XML document, of which it outputs to a text box on a windows app, and then I copy and paste it into elsewhere (rinky dink much?). So as it stands I just do a quick string replace in notepad++ to add the prefix.